# $.POST not posting Data - show the result in snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

The POSTED DATA is EMPTY but why its like this. Pls check!!!

```js
   function AData(mid,murl,mdata)
   {
      $.post( murl, mdata)
        .done(function( data ) {
        $("#res"+mid).html(data);
      });
   } 
   


AData('1','http://api.techsoul.in/movies/techsoul-update-movies.php?token=777&fun=addmovie','{ detail:"PHA%2BTW92aWUgRGV0YWlscyBPZiA6IEFycml2YWwgPC9wPjxiciAvPgo8cD4gQSBNb3ZpZSBEaXJlY3RvciBOYW1lIDogRGVuaXMgVmlsbGVuZXV2ZTwvcD48YnIgLz4KPHA%2BIENhc3RpbmcgSW4gTW92aWUgOiBBbXkgQWRhbXMsIEplcmVteSBSZW5uZXIsIEZvcmVzdCBXaGl0YWtlcjwvcD48YnIgLz4KPHA%2BIFJlbGVhc2VkIFllYXIgOiAyMDE2PC9wPjxiciAvPgo8cD4gQ291bnRyeSBGcm9tIDogVVNBPC9wPjxiciAvPgo8cD4gTGFuZ3VhZ2UgVXNlZCA6IEVuZ2xpc2g8L3A%2BPGJyIC8%2BCjxwPiBHZW5yZXMgc2VlbXMgOiBEcmFtYSwgTXlzdGVyeSwgU2NpLUZpIDwvcD4%3D",category:"aG9sbHl3b29kLW1vdmllcy0yMDE2",poster:"aHR0cDovL29ubGluZW1vdmlld2F0Y2hzLnR2L3dwLWNvbnRlbnQvdXBsb2Fkcy8yMDE2LzExL0Fycml2YWwtTW92aWUtUG9zdGVyLmpwZw%3D%3D",rate:"MA%3D%3D",year:"MjAxNg%3D%3D",quality:"TkE%3D",name:"QXJyaXZhbA%3D%3D",genre:"RHJhbWEsIE15c3RlcnksIFNjaS1GaQ%3D%3D",link:"aHR0cDovL29ubGluZW1vdmlld2F0Y2hzLnR2L2Fycml2YWwtMjAxNi1mdWxsLW1vdmllLW9ubGluZS1mcmVlLWhkLw%3D%3D",src:"aHR0cDovLzE2My4xNzIuMjE0LjEwNS95a2dpcGltZWs2MmJpcm1wbmh3Z3J6bHJlMjZkajI1d29veTZ0Y2Y2MzdhM2ZnamRiY3duanc0c3V3aGEvdi5tcDQ%3D",playersrc:"aHR0cDovL3B1dGxvYWQudHYvZW1iZWQtdDBpNDZodXplMG5lLmh0bWw%3D",status:"MQ%3D%3D",{ detail:"PHA%2BTW92aWUgRGV0YWlscyBPZiA6IEFycml2YWwgPC9wPjxiciAvPgo8cD4gQSBNb3ZpZSBEaXJlY3RvciBOYW1lIDogRGVuaXMgVmlsbGVuZXV2ZTwvcD48YnIgLz4KPHA%2BIENhc3RpbmcgSW4gTW92aWUgOiBBbXkgQWRhbXMsIEplcmVteSBSZW5uZXIsIEZvcmVzdCBXaGl0YWtlcjwvcD48YnIgLz4KPHA%2BIFJlbGVhc2VkIFllYXIgOiAyMDE2PC9wPjxiciAvPgo8cD4gQ291bnRyeSBGcm9tIDogVVNBPC9wPjxiciAvPgo8cD4gTGFuZ3VhZ2UgVXNlZCA6IEVuZ2xpc2g8L3A%2BPGJyIC8%2BCjxwPiBHZW5yZXMgc2VlbXMgOiBEcmFtYSwgTXlzdGVyeSwgU2NpLUZpIDwvcD4%3D",category:"aG9sbHl3b29kLW1vdmllcy0yMDE2",poster:"aHR0cDovL29ubGluZW1vdmlld2F0Y2hzLnR2L3dwLWNvbnRlbnQvdXBsb2Fkcy8yMDE2LzExL0Fycml2YWwtTW92aWUtUG9zdGVyLmpwZw%3D%3D",rate:"MA%3D%3D",year:"MjAxNg%3D%3D",quality:"TkE%3D",name:"QXJyaXZhbA%3D%3D",genre:"RHJhbWEsIE15c3RlcnksIFNjaS1GaQ%3D%3D",link:"aHR0cDovL29ubGluZW1vdmlld2F0Y2hzLnR2L2Fycml2YWwtMjAxNi1mdWxsLW1vdmllLW9ubGluZS1mcmVlLWhkLw%3D%3D",src:"aHR0cDovLzE2My4xNzIuMjE0LjEwNS95a2dpcGltZWs2MmJpcm1wbmh3Z3J6bHJlMjZkajI1d29veTZ0Y2Y2MzdhM2ZnamRiY3duanc0c3V3aGEvdi5tcDQ%3D",playersrc:"aHR0cDovL3B1dGxvYWQudHYvZW1iZWQtdDBpNDZodXplMG5lLmh0bWw%3D",status:"MQ%3D%3D" }');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='res1'></p>
```

Comment: What's your question exactly??

Comment: when i trying to post the data using $.POST. then its going to that webpage and coming back with results but as i am posting the data also using $.POST method of JQuery, this doesnt POST the data.

Answer (score 2):

Because you passing your parameter `mdata`as a string, not as an object. Remove the single quotes before and after, format your json correctly as an array and it works:

```
var details = [
        {
            detail: "PHA%2BTW92aWUgRGV0YWlscyBPZiA6IEFycml2YWwgPC9wPjxiciAvPgo8cD4gQSBNb3ZpZSBEaXJlY3RvciBOYW1lIDogRGVuaXMgVmlsbGVuZXV2ZTwvcD48YnIgLz4KPHA%2BIENhc3RpbmcgSW4gTW92aWUgOiBBbXkgQWRhbXMsIEplcmVteSBSZW5uZXIsIEZvcmVzdCBXaGl0YWtlcjwvcD48YnIgLz4KPHA%2BIFJlbGVhc2VkIFllYXIgOiAyMDE2PC9wPjxiciAvPgo8cD4gQ291bnRyeSBGcm9tIDogVVNBPC9wPjxiciAvPgo8cD4gTGFuZ3VhZ2UgVXNlZCA6IEVuZ2xpc2g8L3A%2BPGJyIC8%2BCjxwPiBHZW5yZXMgc2VlbXMgOiBEcmFtYSwgTXlzdGVyeSwgU2NpLUZpIDwvcD4%3D",
            category: "aG9sbHl3b29kLW1vdmllcy0yMDE2",
            poster: "aHR0cDovL29ubGluZW1vdmlld2F0Y2hzLnR2L3dwLWNvbnRlbnQvdXBsb2Fkcy8yMDE2LzExL0Fycml2YWwtTW92aWUtUG9zdGVyLmpwZw%3D%3D",
            rate: "MA%3D%3D",
            year: "MjAxNg%3D%3D",
            quality: "TkE%3D",
            name: "QXJyaXZhbA%3D%3D",
            genre: "RHJhbWEsIE15c3RlcnksIFNjaS1GaQ%3D%3D",
            link: "aHR0cDovL29ubGluZW1vdmlld2F0Y2hzLnR2L2Fycml2YWwtMjAxNi1mdWxsLW1vdmllLW9ubGluZS1mcmVlLWhkLw%3D%3D",
            src: "aHR0cDovLzE2My4xNzIuMjE0LjEwNS95a2dpcGltZWs2MmJpcm1wbmh3Z3J6bHJlMjZkajI1d29veTZ0Y2Y2MzdhM2ZnamRiY3duanc0c3V3aGEvdi5tcDQ%3D",
            playersrc: "aHR0cDovL3B1dGxvYWQudHYvZW1iZWQtdDBpNDZodXplMG5lLmh0bWw%3D",
            status: "MQ%3D%3D"
        },
        {
            detail: "PHA%2BTW92aWUgRGV0YWlscyBPZiA6IEFycml2YWwgPC9wPjxiciAvPgo8cD4gQSBNb3ZpZSBEaXJlY3RvciBOYW1lIDogRGVuaXMgVmlsbGVuZXV2ZTwvcD48YnIgLz4KPHA%2BIENhc3RpbmcgSW4gTW92aWUgOiBBbXkgQWRhbXMsIEplcmVteSBSZW5uZXIsIEZvcmVzdCBXaGl0YWtlcjwvcD48YnIgLz4KPHA%2BIFJlbGVhc2VkIFllYXIgOiAyMDE2PC9wPjxiciAvPgo8cD4gQ291bnRyeSBGcm9tIDogVVNBPC9wPjxiciAvPgo8cD4gTGFuZ3VhZ2UgVXNlZCA6IEVuZ2xpc2g8L3A%2BPGJyIC8%2BCjxwPiBHZW5yZXMgc2VlbXMgOiBEcmFtYSwgTXlzdGVyeSwgU2NpLUZpIDwvcD4%3D",
            category: "aG9sbHl3b29kLW1vdmllcy0yMDE2",
            poster: "aHR0cDovL29ubGluZW1vdmlld2F0Y2hzLnR2L3dwLWNvbnRlbnQvdXBsb2Fkcy8yMDE2LzExL0Fycml2YWwtTW92aWUtUG9zdGVyLmpwZw%3D%3D",
            rate: "MA%3D%3D",
            year: "MjAxNg%3D%3D",
            quality: "TkE%3D",
            name: "QXJyaXZhbA%3D%3D",
            genre: "RHJhbWEsIE15c3RlcnksIFNjaS1GaQ%3D%3D",
            link: "aHR0cDovL29ubGluZW1vdmlld2F0Y2hzLnR2L2Fycml2YWwtMjAxNi1mdWxsLW1vdmllLW9ubGluZS1mcmVlLWhkLw%3D%3D",
            src: "aHR0cDovLzE2My4xNzIuMjE0LjEwNS95a2dpcGltZWs2MmJpcm1wbmh3Z3J6bHJlMjZkajI1d29veTZ0Y2Y2MzdhM2ZnamRiY3duanc0c3V3aGEvdi5tcDQ%3D",
            playersrc: "aHR0cDovL3B1dGxvYWQudHYvZW1iZWQtdDBpNDZodXplMG5lLmh0bWw%3D",
            status: "MQ%3D%3D"
        }
    ];

    AData(
            '1',
            'http://api.techsoul.in/movies/techsoul-update-movies.php?token=777&fun=addmovie',
            details
    );
```

Edit: In first version on this post, I did not see, that your json was not valid. Look at my answer now and it should work without any errors. Also, please inform youself about the JSON standard and fit it to your needs.

Comment: Sorry this code is giving error. Tell something specific about it.